# Widevine Test content for player validation

Tags: android, drm

I know that the Widevine DRM scheme is supported in the 4+ version of the Android devices. I have created a media player application, how do I validate my player for playback of Widevine evcrypted content.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to get some Widevine content, most likely through one of the Widevine CWIPs as listed here: http://www.widevine.com/cwip/integrators.html

Alternatively you can choose to become a CWIP yourself.